# Having trouble activation Office 365

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-office-2016

I can't activate Office 2016 preview 64bit (tried also 2013 32/64bit with same result).
I'm Office365 subscriber, I was activated until last week. My account is fine ans shows this install as activated in my MS Account dashboard.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the Office 2016 beta have to do with your Office 365 subscription?  The error you have provided is only tied to Office 365 which is NOT the Office 2016 Beta

Comment: @Ramhound I've got Preview 2016 from Office365 account page (32/64bit 2013/2016preview choices). It has worked until last week.

Comment: So you accepted the Office 2016 preview of Office 365.  Are you sure this problem isn't on Microsoft's end?  I know that Office 2016 is suppose to be released next month.

Comment: @Ramhound apparently not. If I remove the install, all other office related apps and delete even registry keys for office apps and install the standard 32bit O2013, it is exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Error 0x8004FC12 when activating Office 2013 or Office 365

> First, run the System File Checker.
>
> Use the System File Checker to run the sfc /scannow command to scan
>   all protected system files and replace the incorrect versions with the
>   correct Microsoft versions. Click on your operating system below and
>   follow the steps to run the System File Checker.
>
> For a Windows 7 PC
>
> 1. Click Start > All Programs > Accessories, and then right-click Command Prompt and choose Run as administrator.
> 2. In the command prompt, type sfc /scannow and press Enter.
> 3. When the system scan is complete, try to install Office again.
>
> For a Windows 8 PC
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search.)
> 2. Enter command prompt in the search box.
> 3. In the list of results, swipe down on or right-click Command Prompt, and then tap or click Run as administrator.
> 4. In the Administrator: Command Prompt window, type sfc /scannow press Enter.
> 5. When the system scan is complete, try to install Office again.
>
> If you ran the System File Checker and you're still having the same
>   problem, you can try performing a Reset or a Reinstall of Windows. You
>   can check out these articles for help:
>
> [For a Windows 7 PC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2255099)
>
> [For a Windows 8 PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

Source ["We’re sorry, something went wrong and we can’t do this for you right now. Please try again later. (0x8004FC12)" when activating Office 2013 or Office 365](http:///)

Comment: Did that, all was fine. I'm on Win10

Comment: @kokesh Please your question to include the windows-10 tag ...

Answer (score -1):

right click on WORD as an example, open WORD with "Administrator Rights", Done!

Office 365 should have a connection, its activated automaticelly........

Comment: Admin rights didn't help, tried that yesterday.